# How to rotate a button in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a button in xamarin, but it does nothing, i also tried to remove Corner radius, so it will not be round, but also, it does nothing. I want to rotate it 180 degrees to flip it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ClickerApp.Page2"
             BackgroundColor="#202020">
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Rotation="0" RotationX="0" RotationY="0">
            <Button RotationY="180" Margin="35" x:Name="button1"  BorderWidth="10" BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="80" WidthRequest="160" HeightRequest="160" Clicked="button1_Clicked" Text="CLICK ME" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Button Margin="35" x:Name="button2"  BorderWidth="10" BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="80"  WidthRequest="160" HeightRequest="160" Clicked="button1_Clicked_1"  Text="CLICK ME" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: What is your final goal from rotating it because it is a circle? put the text from top to bottom? if you don't want it to be round reduce or remove `CornerRadius`

Comment: My goal is to flip the text, so I can make 2 player mode.

Comment: I don't think that's possible in Xamarin.Forms without using a third-party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my code,please run your project to take a look the effect.

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Button
                x:Name="button1"
                Margin="35"
                BorderColor="Gray"
                BorderWidth="10"
                CornerRadius="80"
                HeightRequest="160"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Rotation="180"
                Text="CLICK ME"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="160" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Button
                x:Name="button2"
                Margin="35"
                BorderColor="Gray"
                BorderWidth="10"
                CornerRadius="80"
                HeightRequest="160"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="CLICK ME"
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                WidthRequest="160" />
        </StackLayout>
```

The screenshot :

[image]

Comment: It's not working for me. I guess there's problem in Visual Studio or something...

Comment: @Sale_Jovanovic If you still have problem, please upload your sample at github, I will download your sample to test at my side.

Comment: It's working now, it just didnt show me rotated button in the design. Thank you!

Comment: @Sale_Jovanovic If my reply solved your problem, please mark my reply as answer, it is beneficial to others who face the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you require

[image]

If so, *Rotation="180"*  is the answer

Xaml

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightPink" Padding="20" Margin="0" Spacing="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <Button BackgroundColor="LightGreen" Padding="0" Margin="0" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" CornerRadius="50"
             Text="Up" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
     <Button BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Padding="0" Margin="0" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" CornerRadius="50"
             Text="Down" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Rotation="180"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: @Sale_Jovanovic can you share the screenshot of the result with my code

Comment: Yeah sure, I edited your post and put my screenshot in it :)

Comment: please add a screenshot of the app running, the designer might not be giving the same result as the running app